# How use Maps in Model Class/ Data Classes

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **FirestoreRecyclerView** to display my data on CardViews. It has been smooth sailing so far until I needed to use **map**s:

```
Customers [Collection]
    Customer 1 [Document]
        status: "VIP" [Field]
        name: "Rudolf Heinrich" [Field]
        breakfast [Map]
            meal: "Eggs Benedict" [String]
            coffee: true [Boolean]
            guest: 2 [Int]
        lunch [Map]
            meal: "Tuna" [String]
            coffee: false [Boolean]
            guest: 2 [Int]
        dinner [Map]
            meal: "Zucchini Chicken Alfredo" [String]
            coffee: false [Boolean]
            guest: 2 [Int]
```

My usual **Model Class** goes like the following, but I don't know how to use **map**s like the one above in data classes:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
class CustomerModel (
    var status: String,
    var name: String,
    var breakfast: Map??

) : Parcelable
```

...and how do I retrieve the **Map** data in **onBindViewHolder**?

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: CustomerViewHolder,
    position: Int,
    model: CustomerModel
) {
    holder.status.text = model.status
    holder.name.text = model.name
    holder.meal.text = model.breakfast.meal // is this correct?
    holder.coffee.text = model.breakfast.coffee // is this correct?
    holder.guest.text = model.breakfast.guest // is this correct?
```

Additional question:

What if the Model class requires two **map**s with the same field?

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
class CustomerModel (
    var status: String,
    var name: String,
    var breakfast: Map
    var lunch: Map
    var dinner: Map
```

Do I only need one (1) Map class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer model:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
class CustomerModel (
   var status: String,
   var name: String,
   var breakfast: Map
 ) : Parcelable
```

Map model:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
class Map (
   var meal: String,
   var coffee: Boolean,
   var guest: Int
) : Parcelable
```

**onBindViewHolder** is correct but:

```
holder.status.text = model.status
holder.name.text = model.name
holder.meal.text = model.breakfast.meal 
holder.coffee.text = model.breakfast.coffee.toString() // must be string
holder.guest.text = model.breakfast.guest.toString() // must be string
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad on favs. But using your example, what will happen to variables: "status" and "name"?

Comment: You have to have two models. This is a new one.

Comment: I am confused. Do I need to nest the class Map() within class CustomerModel() or should I create a separate class? Also, I put two (2) ?? on Map?? as I meant to say: "what should I put in here." I cannot use Map as a type because it will require me to provide parameters as in Map<K, V>

Comment: You can put it under. My bad , it will be Map

Comment: Additional question:

What if the Model class requires two **map**s with the same fields, as I have placed in my edit in my original question?

Do I only need one (1) Map class?

Comment: Yes, you can use this way. The important thing is that there are the same variables.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Map model is enough for all of them. Happy coding.